# Create a Button glSurfaceView in Android

Tags: android, button, opengl-es, glsurfaceview

I'm having a bit of a problem with this. I wanted to make a push button. However, I don't know how to use the Button class with [OpenGL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL). I am not using the "R" class within Java instead I am using the old "assets" folder for compatibility.

I have it setup to find if you have touched the button and on "touch up" load the next screen. The flaw in this is that you can touch the screen and then drag your finger over to the button and then lift your finger. The next screen will load, because it has registered the touch up event at that position.

The easiest way to fix this would be to use the Button class, but how do I use it (especially because I won't be able to use `findViewById`)?

This is the code I was using but when onTouchUp check for a collision touchDown has magically changed to be the same as TouchUp?

```
private void onTouchDown(Vector2 point)
{
    if (test.justUp)
    {
        test.setTouchDown(point);
        test.justUp = false;
    }
}
private void onTouchUp(Vector2 point)
{
    test.setTouchUp(point);
    test.justUp = true;

    if(OverlapTester.pointInRectangle(test.bounds, test.touchUp) &&
       OverlapTester.pointInRectangle(test.bounds, test.touchDown))
    {
        game.setScreen(new LevelSelect(game));
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating your own button class, register the "touch down" position and the "touch up" position. If they've both been registered inside your button graphic area, the button is pressed.

Comment: I have code that should do that the only problem is when TouchUp is called it seems to set TouchDown to be at that position as well??

Comment: Are you sure your setTouchDown and setTouchUp method aren't sharing fields, so they won't get overwritten?

Comment: in my Button class there are two variables, one for TouchUp and one for TouchDown, it seems to be a synchronisation issue

Comment: Well, it's easily tested by adding some logging in each of your methods to see how many times and in what order they are getting called. Then move some code accordingly to make it work the way you want.

Comment: Thats the problem I cant seem to fix the issue. It records the down touch correctly and it is never modified again but when it comes to touch up it has suddenly changed even though no method has access it?

Comment: its ok I just made some more variables and made sure they only change once, there is some sync problem though but this workaround prevents it